# Assign a timezone with PHP from a Mysql row reading

Tags: php, mysqli, timezone

Can someone put me on the way on the following : i would like to set timezone with PHP with a value read from Mysql table.

If the value is fetched from Mysql table, the timezone is wrong but i manually set it in the code, it works fine :

This does not work properly :

```
    $query = "SELECT timezone
    FROM `TIMEZONE_table`
    WHERE row_id = 0";
    $timezone_set = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while($row = $timezone_set->fetch_assoc()) 
        {           
            $tmz = $row['timezone'];
            $part_next_event_human->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($tmz));
        }
```

As debug purposes, i tried to display $query variable and it indeed returns the proper timezone as expected :

```
        <?php
            while($row = $timezone_set->fetch_assoc()) 
            {           
                echo "Timezone set : " . $row['timezone']."<br>";
            }

        ?>
```

--> Pacific/Guam

This works properly, if manually entered :

```
    `$part_next_event_human->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Guam'));`
```

Could you please tell me why the Mysql reading is incorrect and not taken in account by setTimezone(new DateTimeZone( ... )) ?

Comment: could you post the result for `echo var_dump($row['timezone'])`
That can be used to determine if you have unexpected spaces, which could be the cause.

Comment: @Adibas03 the `echo` is superfluous.

Comment: try setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(trim($tmz)))?

Comment: Thank you @Asheliahut, `$part_next_event_human->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(trim($tmz)));` gets expected result.